# Please Write Tag Wikis

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

We're in the phase of the site where almost everyone can create new tags. However, there's an important part of a tag that often gets missed out when they get created: the wiki.

I have a rule for myself. If I create a tag, I have to demonstrate that it has value to the site, by writing the tag wiki. I'd like to ask that we all try to do something similar.

Currently, our tags page is full of non-wiki'd tags. I'm going through and editing some of them, but I can't get to all of them by any means. If you can help, please do - writing a tag wiki isn't necessarily onerous. If you don't have much time, just write the excerpt.

The excerpt is especially important because it comes up in the tag's hovercard. It's what defines how the tag should be used - if this explanation isn't there, people may well start using existing tags in ways they weren't intended.

So - if you create a tag, consider writing its wiki or excerpt; and if you've got some spare time, there are a lot of wikiless tags [here](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/tags).

(Note: when writing tag excerpts, the textbox will give you more characters than can actually fit in the hovercard. About one and a bit lines of text will fit; anything more will overflow.)

Comment: [Helpful Meta question.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59415/are-there-any-resources-for-writing-a-tag-wiki) [Also, this page is relevant for excerpts.](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts)

Comment: If anyone's encountering a bug, I've raised it [here](http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/89/are-tag-posts-really-deleted)

Comment: If anything beyond 1 and bit lines overflows, does that mean it doesn't get seen *anywhere*, as you see the full tag wiki rather than the excerpt when you click through?

Comment: @trichoplax It'll get seen in the clickthrough, as *both* display. It also gets seen in the editing dialog.

Answer (score 7):

I do think this is important. However, . . .

Having had one tag wiki excerpt suggestion rejected already, I'll remind everyone about the rejection reason:

> Simply defining what a [tag] is rarely helps those using it unless the tag's name itself is ambiguous. Excerpts should describe why and when a tag should be used. See the [help center](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts) for more guidance.

I would much rather have an excerpt overflow a little bit than leave out important information. Usage is key; succinctness is secondary to completeness, sans extreme cases.

Comment: Happened to me a couple times too. :/ Oh well, I guess we're learning in the process. :)

Answer (score 3):

I've started this, with a few tags, including [license](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/license). However, while doing a complete tag wiki is important, we should get started primarily with tag wiki excerpt. This is what people see when tagging their question, as well as on the tags page.

Comment: Appreciate you helping out :) Keep in mind that the excerpt text box gives you more characters than can fit on the hovercard - about one and a bit lines will fit, anything more overflows.